# killall & pkill can't find a daemon that is running and belongs to me

Tags: macos, shell, terminal

Frequently, I discover that my mouse won't scroll. The solution to this is to quit Logi Options Daemon through the Activity Monitor. I'd like to do this with a shell script, so that I can assign a hotkey, but I can't figure out how to kill the process by name.

```sh
➜  ~ killall "Logi Options Daemon"
No matching processes belonging to you were found
➜  ~ sudo killall "Logi Options Daemon"
Password:
No matching processes were found
➜  ~ sudo killall -9 "Logi Options Daemon"
No matching processes were found
➜  ~ pkill -f "Logi Options Daemon"
➜  ~ pgrep -f "Logi Options Daemon"
```

If I run `ps | grep "Logi Options Daemon"`, I get a different PID each time, but the PID in Activity Moniter isn't changing. Using `kill` with the ID from Activity Monitor, does kill the process, but defeats the purpose of using a script.

How can I make this process die?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this blog post from Chris Pennington](https://chrispennington.blog/blog/how-to-fix-logitech-mx-master-3-not-scrolling-on-mac/), the actual name of the program is `LogiMgrDaemon`, so try:

```
killall LogiMgrDaemon
```

You can find this name in Activity Monitor by selecting the process, opening its Info window (with <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd> or the "I" button in the toolbar), and looking under the Open Files and Ports tab for the binary name & path.

As for what you see when you run `ps | grep "Logi Options Daemon"`, you're probably just seeing the `grep` process itself. Note the "grep" in the process listing here:

```
$ ps | grep "No Such Daemon"
36074 ttys006    0:00.00 grep No Such Daemon
```

This is an extremely common problem with `ps | grep`, and pretty much the entire reason that `pgrep` exists as a separate program.

Comment: That's the answer. Thanks.